# Android - Cropped image so much zoomed and looking blurre

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I am using following code to crop an image taken from the camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");              
intent .setDataAndType(outputFileUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("outputX",600);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 600);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", false); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

My problems are:

1. Image cropping is working good on some devices and on some devices app is crashing.So how to handle this condition?
2. Another thing is that cropped image too much zoomed and getting blurre.

Comment: @Michaël If i get suitable answer, I will definitely accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too large photo causes crash, see this [how to crop large photos](http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android).

Comment: Hi user1705590, i have already gone through this code sample. Just i want that how to check whether inbuilt crop app available in device or not.Because after that we have to handle onActivityResult also.