# I want to crop an image and type was view in image. How can I crop an image from camera using this type of cropping?

Tags: android, image, crop

**How can I crop a image?** I have tried some concepts using intents but still failed.. I want this type of cropping.

Here's a image:
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: i just want to crop image just like display above link.there are 8 point for cropping and i want to adjust cropping point  from this 8 point.i use CropImageview library but unable to crop image.

Comment: https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView here this was a link which library i can use .

Comment: can you share the project? or some code? maybe something goes wrong...

Comment: in simple i wann take a pic from camera n crop that image like you see in image how can i do that i use that library  but that cant help me .

Answer (score 0):

1.Have an Activity with your `CropImageView` in it's layout.
2.Start the camera activity with an `Intent`with a `startActivityForResult` to take the picture. 
3.In the Activity, override `onActivityResult` to take the picture bitmap and do `CropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) and voila! Now you can crop it...
Have a look at this one for an example:
[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Try out following code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 1; 
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, opts);
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");              
intent .setDataAndType(outputFileUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("outputX",bm.getWidth());
intent.putExtra("outputY", bm.getHeight());
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", false); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

following parameters play vital role:

```
 intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
```

For more info:
[Android - Crop image taken from camera with resizable ,independant height and width of cropped area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873994/android-crop-image-taken-from-camera-with-resizable-independant-height-and-wi)

Comment: this type of crop image i already done i want that type of cropping which i view in que. see that thank you for advice

Answer (score 0):

Have a xml file for your activity where you will display the original image in the main_imageview and add another imageview as child to the crop_main_layout having the crop rect image as src (9 patch image)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crop_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="@dimen/crop_view_padding"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The crop rect image view can be a custom class deriving from Imageview which will handle all onTouchEvents and will provide resize/move functionality and once user selects the selection and presses Done on your crop screen, crop the image using the selected crop rect (custom crop rect image view bounds).

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(currentBitmap, cropRect.left, cropRect.top, cropRect.width(), cropRect.height());
```